# Crystal Report Printing Issue with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, adobe, acrobat

I have Crystal Reports version 13.0.6. My Acrobat Reader is 11.3. I have recently shifted over to Windows 7 and am attempting to print reports. The same reports that worked fine in Windows XP are printing quite odd in Windows 7.

I have tried printing both in Crystal Report Viewer and as a PDF.  I get the same result.

The first page prints fine, but any following pages are squeezed down to the bottom left or top right corner into a small rectangle instead of covering the entire page.

Comment: Have you tried selecting No Printer (optimize for screen display) and  Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer paper size options in the Page Setup of the report?